# Good-looking German-style quotes around math

Tags: math-mode, quoting

I want to use this type of quotation marks inside math mode: *„quote“*. (This type of quotation marks is used in Germany, as well as Poland and Czechia.) However, I want the opening quotation mark to be at the bottom and the closing mark to be at the top of the enquoted expression.

So far, I've tried these two options:

```latex
\begin{gather*}
    \text{„} \frac{1}{2} \text{“}
    \quad
    \text{\enquote{$\frac{1}{2}$}}
\end{gather*}
```

[image: unsatisfactory result]

But, as you can see, both these options put the quotation marks directly on the baseline, not around the enquoted fraction. The result I want to achieve would look more like this:

[image: good result]

Comment: Please tell us (a) which TeX distribution you employ, (b) when it was last updated, and (c) with which options you load the `csquotes` and `babel` packages.

Comment: I'm using Xetex – both locally (TeX Live 2019/Debian) and on Overleaf. I load babel with `\usepackage[czech]{babel}`. I usually use the symbols „“ directly instead of `csquotes`, but for this example I loaded the package without any options using `\usepackage{csquotes}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses a macro I call `\kludgequote`. Observe that it doesn't require the `babel` and `csquotes` packages.

The code shown below runs under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. To run it under pdfLaTeX, just replace `\usepackage{fontspec}` with `\usepackage[T1]{fontspec}`.

[image]

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\prescript" macro
\newcommand\kludgequote[1]{%
    \prescript {} {\text{\normalsize„}} {\mkern-1.5mu#1} 
    {\vphantom{#1}}^{\mkern-1.5mu\text{\normalsize\raisebox{-0.5ex}{“}}}}
\begin{document}
„hhh“
„$\frac{1}{2}$“  
$\kludgequote{\frac{1}{2}}$
$\kludgequote{\dfrac{1}{2}}$
\end{document}
```